# Polymorphism in JavaScript to have different constructors

Tags: javascript, oop

I am new to JavaScript, I have been working in Java and C++, there we have polymorphism for Constructors; Example:

```
class Car
{
     Car()
     {
         ....
         //body
         ....
     }
     Car(int speed, string body_type)
     {
          ....
          //body
          ....
     }
};
```

I was trying object oriented programming in JavaScript using the same concept. I wrote this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function bike()
    {
        this.bike_type="scooter";
    this.bike_bidy="metal";
        this.bike_speed=40;
        document.write('bike instantiated with type:'+this.bike_type);  
    }
    function bike(type, body, speed)
    {
        this.bike_type=type;
        this.bike_bidy=body;
        this.bike_speed=speed;
        document.write('bike instantiated with type:'+type);    
    }
    bike1 = new bike("harley","metal",120);
    bike2 = new bike();
    document.write(bike1.bike_type);
    document.write(bike2.bike_speed);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But here, I get instance only for the `bike()` *function/class* not for `bike(type, body, speed)`. When I tried this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function bike(type, body, speed)
    {
        this.bike_type=type;
        this.bike_bidy=body;
        this.bike_speed=speed;
        document.write('bike instantiated with type:'+type);    
    }
    function bike()
    {
        this.bike_type="scooter";
    this.bike_bidy="metal";
        this.bike_speed=40;
        document.write('bike instantiated with type:'+this.bike_type);  
    }
    bike1 = new bike("harley","metal",120);
    bike2 = new bike();
    document.write(bike1.bike_type);
    document.write(bike2.bike_speed);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I get, instance for `function bike(type, body, speed)` not for `bike()`. I understood that it is only taking the 1st definition. And the way I am doing is not allowed.

How can I make a polymorphic constructor in JavaScript? Is it possible?

Comment: **CAPS AND BOLD EQUALS SHOUTING**. Never appropriate on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. In both cases, the second function definition overwrites the first.

You have to examine your arguments from within your function, and alter your functions behaviour accordingly.

In your case, you can simply use defaults if none were given:

```
function bike(type, body, speed)
{
    this.bike_type = type || "scooter";
    this.bike_bidy = body || "metal";
    this.bike_speed = speed || 40;
}
```

It is also very common to use a single options argument, something like `bike({body: "carbon fiber"})`, allowing you to omit leading parameters without having to specify `undefined` in their place.

```
function bike(options)
{
    this.bike_type = options.type || "scooter";
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That will cause problems with any passed-in arguments which evaluate to false - for instance, `bike("broken", "metal", 0)` will give you a bike with `speed` of 40.

Answer (score 4):

In Javascript:

- a global function can only be defined once
- function arguments are optional
- function arguments are available through a pseudo-array called `arguments` (see [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)).

So you can do something like this:

```
function bike(type, body, speed)
{
    if (arguments.length >= 3) {
        this.bike_type = type;
        this.bike_body = body;
        this.bike_speed = speed;
        document.write('bike instantiated with type:'+type);    
    } else {
        this.bike_type = "scooter";
        this.bike_body = "metal";
        this.bike_speed = 40;
        document.write('bike instantiated with type:'+this.bike_type);  
    }
}
```